# Изменение значение span в зависимости от изменения value у select

Tags: jquery, html5

Создал скрипт на jQuery, но почему то содержимое span не изменяется от изменения значений в select. Не пойму никак в чем здесь ошибки.
Если честно, то вижу какая то громадная конструкция получается и однотипная

```js
(length, duration, quantity).addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (length.value === 'General',
    duration.value === 'lesDur-30',
    quantity.value === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("4");
  } else if (length.value === 'General',
    duration.value === 'lesDur-60',
    quantity.value === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("8");
  } else if (length.value === 'Exams',
    duration.value === 'lesDur-30',
    quantity.value === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("12");
  } else if (length.value === 'Exams',
    duration.value === 'lesDur-60',
    quantity.value === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("16");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="calculator">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="payment__cup">LESSON PLANS</h3>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <label for="length">French course</label>
        <select id="length" name="length">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="General">General Course</option>
          <option value="Exams">Exams Preparation</option>
          <option value="General">Conversational French</option>
          <option value="Exams">Business French</option>
          <option value="Exams">Civilisation française</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <label for="duration">Lesson duration</label>
        <select id="duration" name="duration">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="lesDur-30">30 minutes</option>
          <option value="lesDur-60">60 minutes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity of lessons</label>
        <select id="quantity" name="quantity">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="Quantity-4">4 lessons</option>
          <option value="Quantity-8">8 lessons</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <div class="submit-block">
          <p>This French course costs : <span id="result-culc"></span> euros</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#length, #duration, #quantity").change(function() {

  if ($("#length").val() === 'General' &&
    $("#duration").val() === 'lesDur-30' &&
    $("#quantity").val() === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("4");
  } else if ($("#length").val() === 'General' &&
    $("#duration").val() === 'lesDur-60' &&
    $("#quantity").val() === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("8");
  } else if ($("#length").val() === 'Exams' &&
    $("#duration").val() === 'lesDur-30' &&
    $("#quantity").val() === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("12");
  } else if ($("#length").val() === 'Exams' &&
    $("#duration").val() === 'lesDur-60' &&
    $("#quantity").val() === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("16");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="calculator">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="payment__cup">LESSON PLANS</h3>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <label for="length">French course</label>
        <select id="length" name="length">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="General">General Course</option>
          <option value="Exams">Exams Preparation</option>
          <option value="General">Conversational French</option>
          <option value="Exams">Business French</option>
          <option value="Exams">Civilisation française</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <label for="duration">Lesson duration</label>
        <select id="duration" name="duration">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="lesDur-30">30 minutes</option>
          <option value="lesDur-60">60 minutes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity of lessons</label>
        <select id="quantity" name="quantity">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="Quantity-4">4 lessons</option>
          <option value="Quantity-8">8 lessons</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <div class="submit-block">
          <p>This French course costs : <span id="result-culc"></span> euros</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

А где вы откопали такой синтаксис?

> `(length, duration, quantity).addEventListener('change', function() {`

Укажите правильный селектор и все будет работать

```js
$('.calculator').on('change', 'select', function() {
  if (length.value === 'General',
    duration.value === 'lesDur-30',
    quantity.value === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("4");
  } else if (length.value === 'General',
    duration.value === 'lesDur-60',
    quantity.value === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("8");
  } else if (length.value === 'Exams',
    duration.value === 'lesDur-30',
    quantity.value === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("12");
  } else if (length.value === 'Exams',
    duration.value === 'lesDur-60',
    quantity.value === 'Quantity-4') {
    $("#result-culc").html("16");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="calculator">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="payment__cup">LESSON PLANS</h3>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <label for="length">French course</label>
        <select id="length" name="length">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="General">General Course</option>
          <option value="Exams">Exams Preparation</option>
          <option value="General">Conversational French</option>
          <option value="Exams">Business French</option>
          <option value="Exams">Civilisation française</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <label for="duration">Lesson duration</label>
        <select id="duration" name="duration">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="lesDur-30">30 minutes</option>
          <option value="lesDur-60">60 minutes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity of lessons</label>
        <select id="quantity" name="quantity">
          <option value="0"></option>
          <option value="Quantity-4">4 lessons</option>
          <option value="Quantity-8">8 lessons</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap-calc">
        <div class="submit-block">
          <p>This French course costs : <span id="result-culc"></span> euros</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

А по поводу громоздкости конструкции - вы опишите, как оно должно работать, а мы заоптимизируем.